# Unable to install system.speech package into VS project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, macos, visual-studio

I am currently using Visual Studio Community 2017 for Mac and i have a .net MVC solution setup. I am trying to add a reference to system.speech. I have found System.Speech.dll to download via nuget when adding packages, however when i click add package, i get an error in the Package Console saying `"incompatible package, rolling back changes"`.

Can anyone help at all?

P.S I have recently only started learning development so go easy on the terminology ;)

Thanks

Comment: Try check with https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c976116b-ab81-46bc-8d29-df2fd859393b/system-speech-api-is-not-supported-in-net-framework-for-macos?forum=netfxbcl or https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/315347/adding-systemspeech-in-c-project-on-visual-studio.html.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Hopefully this will be something they can look at in the 2019 version of VS for Mac.